# Is there any review paper on spatial light modulator?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics

I need a review paper on the various types, principles and characterization of spatial light modulator. But it seems I could not find one. Any one has a good idea?

Comment: I don't know of a review paper, but I have a [technical report](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275346882_Orbital_angular_momentum_mode_analysis_with_a_micro_mirror_array) from quite a while back, about characterizing a micro mirror array, which is a specific type of spatial light modulator.

Answer (score 1):

Characterization of a spatial light modulator
https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03297